# EF Core Migrations on Start Up From Loan Balanced API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I use the following code to automatically run EF Core 2.0 migrations when my ASP.NET Core 2.0 API starts (`StartUp.cs` class):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices
                          .GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                          .CreateScope())
    {
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

I am planning to load balance the API. Assuming that both API instances start at the same time, would EF Core migration system be smart enough to lock the database so the migrations run only once or should I write that code myself? I don't see any locking code when browsing [the `Migrator` class](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/Internal/Migrator.cs).

Thank you!

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to do something like migrate on startup anyways. This should really be part of your release pipeline. Things can go awry in a schema update, and you want to be able to roll back, not just from the database change but also the dependent code, which this will never give you.

Comment: @ChrisPratt can you please expand on what can go wrong? Any references you would recommend?

Comment: Chris explained it pretty well.  You can't roll back in toto.  What specifically are you unclear about?